# How to version some sub folders in a project with git?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have a PHP project folder, which has too many files ,
it will be very time wasting ,if you use `git init`  in the project root folder.
Now I just want to version some folders only,

```
--------------
FolderA
----data
----class
------class1
------class2
----html
------front
------backend
---------------
```

I want to version `class` and `front` only,

How to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Don’t `git add` the other files and folders, and probably add their paths to a `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1):

`git init` only creates a blank Git repository, there is nothing that makes this more time consuming for larger directories compared to empty ones.

To create a Git repository for `FolderA` and add the `class` and `html/front` directory to it, do the following:

```
cd FolderA
git init
git add class
git add html/front
git commit
```

If you want to keep the other folders out, it’s a good idea to also create a `.gitignore` file with the following contents:

```
/data
/html/backend
```

Save that into the folder `FolderA` and also add it to the repository using `git add` and committing that change.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file and choose:

1. Exclude everything except the two folders you want to version
2. Include everything and exclude the folders you do not want to version

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to use submodule.
Submodule is a git project inside another git project.

Each project will *live* in its own folder (=submodule) and is isolated from the 
root folder which mean that its a standalone project. As such a project you can mange your version on this repo.

Here is a sample of submodule inside root repository
[image]